# Whenever I run my android application it stopped as it is i clicked the login button

Tags: android

53rd line is this:

```
HttpsURLConnection httpsURLConnection=(HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();
```

24th line is this:

public class BackGroundWork extends AsyncTask]

The image i attached is the error which is found in error list .

Comment: Please edit your question and paste the Java stack trace in **as text**. That is important in general, so the question is not dependent upon some image that may go away, and so people can find this question in searches when searching upon words that appear in the stack trace. In this specific case, your image cuts off the important parts.

Answer (score 0):

```
  try this codes below: 

 URL url = new URL(Link);
  URLConnection connect = url.openConnection();





@Override
protected Object doInBackground(Object[] objects) {
    try {
        String data = URLEncoder.encode("tableName", "UTF8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(TableName, "UTF8") + "&" + "record" + "=" + RecordNo;
        //data
        URL url = new URL(Link);
        URLConnection connect = url.openConnection();
        connect.setDoOutput(true);
        OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(connect.getOutputStream());
        wr.write(data);
        wr.flush();
        String S = convetInputStreamToString(connect.getInputStream());

        assert S != null;
        if (!S.equals("no")) {
            GetUpdates.access = true;
            GetUpdates.res = S;
        } else {
            GetUpdates.access = false;
            GetUpdates.err = S;
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "";
}
```

Comment: URL url = new URL(Link);
  URLConnection connect = url.openConnection();